# C# GoogleSheets Update Request not Executing

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to update values in a Google Spreadsheet, The code executes up to the `addRequest.Execute();` however, it does not run the execute statement.
This does work  if i run a Append Request, however im not trying to append, im trying to update. 
I have the following Scopes for the program `static readonly string[] Scope = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, DriveService.Scope.Drive};`

```cs
var range = $"{ClashImport[i][0].ToString()}!B7:F106";
var REALInsertList = new sData.ValueRange();
var InsertList = new List<object>();

for (int n = 0; n < DataImport[i].Count; n++) {
    InsertList.Add(DataImport[i][n].AccountName);
    InsertList.Add(DataImport[i][n].AccountID);
    InsertList.Add(DataImport[i][n].Banned);
    InsertList.Add(DataImport[i][n].Suspended);
    InsertList.Add(DataImport[i][n].History);
}

REALInsertList.Values = new List<IList<object>> { InsertList };
var addRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(REALInsertList, SheetToImportTo, range);
addRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
addRequest.Execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example will help you to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
 // Define request parameters.
 // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
 string spreadsheetId = "YOUR-SPREADSHEET-ID";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

 // How the input data should be interpreted.
 string valueInputOption = "RAW";  // TODO: Update placeholder value. Ex -> RAW

 // The new values to apply to the spreadsheet.
 List<ValueRange> data = new List<ValueRange>(); // Instanciate a list of type ValueRange
 ValueRange values = new ValueRange(); // Instanciate a ValueRange object
 values.Range = "A1:B2"; // The range you want to update
 // Depending in your number of rows, create some logic to populate them 
 List<object> firstRow = new List<object> { "Hello", 2};
 List<object> secondRow = new List<object> { 3, "Hey!"};
 // Populate the values to be inserted in the sheet
 values.Values = new List<IList<object>> { firstRow, secondRow };
 // add values to the data ValueRange List
 data.Add(values);

 // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
 BatchUpdateValuesRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
 requestBody.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption;
 requestBody.IncludeValuesInResponse = true;
 requestBody.Data = data;

 // Build and make the request
 SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchUpdateRequest request 
     = service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(requestBody, spreadsheetId);
 BatchUpdateValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
 IList<IList<object>> updatedValues = response.Responses[0].UpdatedData.Values;

 // Print updated values 
 Console.WriteLine("These are the updated values");
 foreach (var row in updatedValues)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[1]);
 }

 Console.Read();
```

Following the [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%2217SUY2bDDvugu-XU-rqeKPVQ4qY405KaFUzuchwVNcjM%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22includeValuesInResponse%22%3Atrue%2C%22data%22%3A%5B%7B%22range%22%3A%22A1%3AB2%22%2C%22values%22%3A%5B%5B%22A1%22%2C%22B1%22%5D%2C%5B%22A2%22%2C%22B2%22%5D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22valueInputOption%22%3A%22RAW%22%7D%7D) endpoint documentation and the *Try this API*, I was able to get an idea on how to build the request update body.
Notice I created a [`List<ValueRange>`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1Data_1_1ValueRange.html), which I populate with the appropriate data and in that way make the request.

### Documentation

For more info, you can check:

- [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet)
- [Google Sheets API .NET reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this whole writing to Spreadsheets. This worked! (thanks for the comments, helps me to understand what I'm needing to do)